# License plate combinations 4 letters 3 numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

How many license plates can be created if they have $4$ letters and $3$ digits in any order?

My thinking is $26^4 \times 10^3 \times {7 \choose 4} \times {7 \choose 3}$:

$26$ possibilities for each of 4 letters, $10$ possibilities for each of 3 digits, $4$ places out of $7$ to place the letters, and $3$ places out of $7$ to place the numbers.

Is this correct?

Comment: Almost.  By choosing the four positions occupied by letters we know that the remaining positions must be occupied by digits.  There is no need to select which positions they are again.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok, that makes since because I know n choose k = n choose n-k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reiterating what was said earlier in a comment:

Your answer is almost correct however you made the mistake of picking the positions twice rather than only once.  By choosing the four positions to be occupied by letters and then again choosing which three positions were to be occupied by digits and having chosen said positions out of the original seven, you will have run the risk of picking the same position multiple times designating it to be simultaneously used by letter *and* digit.

Instead, the digits' positions should have been selected out of the remaining *unused* positions giving a total of $\binom{3}{3}=1$ way in which this step could be accomplished, this being merely $1$ way it can be left out of the final product.  This leaves the final answer as being:

$$26^4\cdot 10^3\cdot \binom{7}{4}$$

---

Compare this to a slightly larger problem where you have $26$ letters to choose from, $10$ digits, and $15$ special symbols (e.g. !@#\$%^ and so on...) and we want to make a ten-character password consisting of $6$ letters, $3$ digits, and $1$ special symbol with repetition allowed.

We first pick the positions used by letters, then *from those remaining positions* pick the positions used by digits, letting the final remaining position be occupied by the symbol, and then picking which letters, digits, and symbol they happened to be for a total count of:

$$26^6\cdot 10^3\cdot 15\cdot \binom{10}{6}\cdot \binom{4}{3}$$

Answer (score -1):

There are 28 letters and 10 digts from 0 to 9. You want to chose 7 of them when the order in which you select is important. So there are $P_{38}^7$ possibilites. ($P$ stands for permutation)

Comment: Repetition is not mentioned and so should be assumed to be allowed.

Comment: When repetition is allowed you use Permutation! No?! Is this why you gave a negative?!

Comment: When repetition is **not** allowed you use permutations.  The general case when it is (*or isn't*) allowed you use rule of product.

Comment: Further, you completely ignored the requirement of exactly three digits being used and exactly four letters being used.  your answer of $38\frac{7}{~}=38\cdot 37\cdot 36\cdots 32$ gives the number of sequences of seven characters where we don't care about the number of appearing digits or letters.  It included in the count scenarios where they were all digits or all letters, etc...  Even further, you used $28$ as the number of letters when it is presumed to be the English alphabet which has only $26$ letters, not $28$.  This is reinforced by the fact the OP used the number $26$ in the attempt